# find pattern getting from file in directory with files

Tags: shell, grep

i have first file with 3 lines :

```
test1  
test2  
test3
```

i use the grep cmd to search every lines from directory with 10 files :

> grep -Ril "test2"

result is :

> /usr/src/files/rog.txt

i need grep to delete the 5 lines from the finiding file , 2 lines before and 2 after `test2`

please can help me for good grep use .

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to use the -A and -B options of grep. But to use it, you need to perform two steps.
First you select all matches with the previous and next line and with that list, but that would have some side effects (which in your application are probably acceptable).

To do this, you issue the following commands:
`grep -A 2 -B 2 "test2" file1.txt > negative.txt
grep -v -f negative.txt file1.txt`

The first line outputs all findings of test2 in file1.txt accompanied by the 2 preceding and 2 succeeding lines of each line found. If I got your question right, this is the "negative" of the lines you want. The second line now lists all lines from file1.txt which do not correspond to a "negative line". This should be close to what you need. 
There is only one side effect which you should know. If file1.txt contains duplicate lines like this:

`test1 
test2 
test3 
test4 
...
test11 
test12 
test3 
test4`

The code above would also filter out the two last lines, even though there is no "test2" line near because they are duplicates of the lines 3 and 4 which were written to "negative.txt" because of line 2. But if you're processing file lists probably duplicates are no issue.